# detect words inside embed fields

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

I'm currently programming a discord bot.
The bot's task will be to detect a username and a word in an embed to give the specific user a coin.
The embed will be sent by the DISBOARD bot, but for now, another bot of my own is sending a template. 
The only code I found and adapted to my bot only works with the title, but not for the field.name neither for the field.value.

```
    if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('undefined'))
message.channel.send("checked!");
else {
    for(var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
        if(message.embeds[i].title.includes("Test") || message.embeds[i].title.includes("Test")) {
            message.channel.send("checked!");
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to transform this code to embed.field and embed.value but I just receive error messages.

And does anyone know which method is the best to save the balances of the players?
May anyone know about this and can help me?

Thank you!

Comment: Hello.  To help further assist you, would you mind adding the error message to your post?

Comment: embed.field is not a thing.  ``embed.fields`` is an array, you will have to search through each one.  You have one loop there, you need an internal loop to iterate over each of the fields.

Answer (score 0):

So as Tarazed said: `embed.fields` is an array of the fields that contain a `.name` and a `.value` as text that you can search through. Try the following:

```js
if(message.content.toLowerCase().includes('undefined')) message.channel.send("undefined check!");
else {
    var sent = false;
    for(var i = 0; i < message.embeds.length; i++) {
        if(message.embeds[i].title.toLowerCase().includes("test")) {
            message.channel.send("checked!");
            break;
        } else{
            for(var j = 0;j < message.embeds[i].fields.length;j++){
                if(message.embeds[i].fields[j].name.toLowerCase().includes("test") || message.embeds[i].fields[j].value.toLowerCase().includes("test")){
                  message.channel.send("checked!");
                  sent = true;
                  break;
                }
            }
            if(sent) break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey again! Thank you for your answers. I tried the code, but it doesn't work. I don't receive error messages, but it doesn't send a message as response. My embed is built the following: `switch(args[0]){
        case 'embed':
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
            .setTitle('Test Embed')
            .addField('test', 'example')
            .setColor(0xB73BEA)
            message.channel.send(embed);
            break;` I adapted your code with example and test but it doesnt work at all. It just says one time checked! because of the working Test as title line.

Comment: So first off. I have no clue why the first if statement that checks the `.title` isn't running. Please add a `console.log(message.embeds[0])` to see if it's actually seeing the correct embed. Or if it's registering a different message. It's possible `message` isn't set to the message that contains the embed.

Also I update the code to include a `.toLowerCase()` inside it.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while searching for solution but I think I have some updated information. as mentioned by @Frustrated programmer, fields are an array, but embed is object. you can find fields data under embed.data.fields

```
EmbedBuilder { data: { color: 65535, fields: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

you can read fields like this:

```
embed.data.fields[0]
```

edit: my discord.js version is 8.11.0